# how to execute javascript function on dynamically created button's click event.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my HTML display I have a table showing some names of uploaded files. and a button to delete  that file.

the names of files are loaded dynamically by Php

```
<tbody>
               <?php
                    foreach ($uploaded_files as $val) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <a href="delete_this_file/<?php echo $val['id']; ?>" class="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?"><div class="btn btn-danger">Delete</div></a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <?php echo $val['file_name']; ?>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
```

and I have a javascript function in my html head section like this, to confirm did he really want to delete it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        var deleteLink = document.querySelector('.delete');
                        deleteLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();

                            var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

                            if (choice) {
                                window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

this is working well only for first button only, and for other buttons it is redirecting to this link href="delete_this_file/

can some one show me the error in this code. I can't figure it out.

Thank You very Much

Comment: can you explain the difference between 'working well' and 'redirecting' ?

Comment: working well means it give that confirmation box before redirecting to delete controller. 

in the other case it is redirecting without giving that confirmation box.

:)

Comment: what property of the file do u send to the controller to remove file accordingly?

Comment: why do you want to make so much complexity, just add onclick="somefunction(this.id)" while iterating itself, then you can write a mimimized function, which does this checking

Comment: the id of the file in the mysql table.

Comment: your HTML is invalid. Tbody can't have th.

Comment: @RaviMone -  I thought it is not a good practice. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this link:
https://api.jquery.com/on/

the `on` method will bind events to dynamically created objects

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
    //your code here
});
```

**When you use the regular addEventListener, it binds it only to the current matching elements on the DOM, any matching element created after this point, will not be binded**

Comment: Extra info link about "delegation": https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Thank You Mrs.Shay Elkayam and Mr.Veritas87 
with your help I could make it right. 

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
               <?php
                    foreach ($uploaded_files as $val) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="deleteFun(<?php echo $val['id']; ?>)" class="delete"><div class="btn btn-danger">Delete</div></a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <?php echo $val['file_name']; ?>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
    <script>
    function deleteFun(id){

    var choice = confirm("Are you sure to delete this item?");

       if (choice) {
           window.location.href = "delete_this_file/"+id;
       }
    }

    <script>
```

just Try this, more minimized answer